# PXE Installing Ubuntu 20.04 by way of preseed.cfg doesn't start

Tags: 20.04, .desktop, preseed, pxe

I'm trying to PXE boot my Ubuntu 20.04 desktop by way of a preseed.cfg file. I have PXE boot menu working just fine, I can boot to and install a normal Ubuntu 20.04 box this way.

The problem is the preseed.cfg file, my desktop does not seem to start it. I can see the file being served from my PXE server to the client and the client logs show it downloaded into /tmp

... my casper.log file ...

```
Begin: Loading preseed file...  http://192.168.0.155/preseed/preseed.cfg
Saving to: '/tmp/preseed.cfg'
```

When the VM starts, it shows the normal Ubuntu 20 try / install menu. If I fire up a terminal and I look under /tmp, I do not see the file there

```
ls /tmp/preseed.cfg
ls: cannot access '/tmp/preseed.cfg': No such file or directory
```

Again, though, I see the file downloaded in my /var/log/casper.log file

My preseed.cfg file (shown below) is incomplete, I just wanted to get it read and the install process started

preseed.cfg

```
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
d-i console-setup/layoutcode string us
d-i keyboard-configuration/layoutcode string us
d-i netcfg/enable boolean true
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto
d-i netcfg/hostname string newhost.mydomain.com
```

my pxelinux.cfg default file

```
default vesamenu.c32
menu default
label ubuntu2004
kernel ubuntu2005/vmlinuz
append vga=normal initrd=ubuntu2004/initrd ip=dhcp netboot=nfs auto=true url=http://192.168.0.155/preseed/preseed.cfg nfsroot=192.168.0.155:/netboot/nfs/ubuntu2004/ splash fsck.mode=skip --
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what I was doing wrong. Rather than using the desktop image for my PXE server, I should have been using Ubuntu Netboot images

Example software here:

[Ubuntu Focal Netboot](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/20101020ubuntu614/legacy-images/netboot/)

The files to use are:

```
ubuntu-installer/amd64/linux
ubuntu-installer/amd64/initrd.gz
```

Thus, my PXE should look like:

```
default vesamenu.c32
menu default
label ubuntu2004
kernel ubuntu2004/linux
append vga=normal initrd=ubuntu2004/initrd.gz ip=dhcp netboot=nfs auto=true url=http://192.168.0.155/preseed/preseed.cfg splash fsck.mode=skip --
```